# Angular 6 - How to set dynamic type in html input using angular input decorator

Tags: angular, decorator, angular-components, html-input

I'm passing dynamic type to input using angular `@Input` decorator. It's doesn't working and showing NaN value => `type="NaN"`. How I can acheive this? Here is my code:

**datepicker.html**

```
<input  class="{{ value ? 'has-value' : '' }}"
        type="{{inputType}}"
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        [max]="getToday()"/>
```

**datepicker.ts**

```
@Input() inputType: string;
```

**app.html**

```
<app-datepicker [inputType]="datetime-local"[(ngModel)]="example1"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>

<app-datepicker [inputType]="date"[(ngModel)]="example2"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `''` to your bindings, otherwise the datepicker assumes that you are passing an object, not a string. Like this: `[inputType]="'datetime-local'"`

```
<app-datepicker [inputType]="'datetime-local'"[(ngModel)]="example1"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>

<app-datepicker [inputType]="'date'"[(ngModel)]="example2"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `[]` from the attribute like this:
Then you do not need to add the `''`

```
<app-datepicker inputType="datetime-local"[(ngModel)]="example1"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>

<app-datepicker inputType="date"[(ngModel)]="example2"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"></app-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `type` to a variable in

### ChildComponent.html

```
<input [type]='type'>
```

### ChildComponent.ts

```
@Input() type;
```

### App.component.html

```
<select (change)='change($event)'>
  <option>number</option>
  <option>date</option>
  <option>datetime-local</option>
</select>

<app-child [type]='type'></app-child>

{{type}}
```

### App.component.ts

```
type;
change(ev ) {
 this.type = event.target.value;
}
```